# Bootstrap 4 sticky footer issue

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, footer

I'm kinda new to web-development using bootstrap and I'm trying to achieve something with my footer...

Actually my footer is looking like this for the desktop version of my website:

[image]

the footer elements are displayed in line without any issue...

But if I change the page's resolution until I reach the mobile design of it my footer elements are stacked on top of each others instead of still being inline:

[image]

I tried to fix that to use media queries and `css`, to add a `display : inline-block` to the `html` list but it didn't worked, and I don't really know what I should use to keept it displayed correctly.

Here is the code pen of the footer :
https://codepen.io/rgmislife/pen/poJJeyV

```css
.footer-page {
  background-color: #d2d7e8;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  /**position:absolute;**/
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .footer-page {
    position: relative;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .footer-page {
    position: absolute;
  }
}

.navbar-brand {
  font-family: 'Raleway', regular;
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.icon {
  font-size: 0.4rem;
}

.nav-link {
  font-family: 'Raleway', Semi-Bold;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #3a5199;
  font-size: 15px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  no
}
```

```html
<link href="//use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<footer>
  <div class="footer-page">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom navbar-expand-md bg-faded justify-content-center">
      <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand d-flex w-50 mr-auto">Brand</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsingNavbar3">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100" id="collapsingNavbar3">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fab fa-linkedin fa-2x"></i></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item d-inline-block">
            <a class="nav-link" href="nous-contacter.php"><i class="fas fa-envelope fa-2x"></i></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto w-100 justify-content-end">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="nous-contacter.php">Nous contacter</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="mentions.html">Mentions Légales</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="CGV.html">CGV</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="presse.html">Presse</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="evenements.html">Evénements</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</footer>
```

and thats is the `css` code I tried :

```
.nav li {display: inline-block;}
```

If anyone has an idea feel free to let me know.
Thanks.

Comment: I can see two ul's in the div collapsingnavbar3 .. is that both required ?

Comment: if i understood you correctly, i do have 2 ULs tag in my footer for placement purposes they both have their own bootstrap class to either center the elements or place them to the left or right so yeah they are required for design purposes.

Comment: What I was trying to understand is that, I don't see any data in the top ul so if you remove that and put the container to display:block .. You can fix the issue but since I'm not sure about your final result I can't give a proper answer.

Comment: If you can show me what you talk about in a codepen it might help me to understand, the final goal is to force the elements of the footer to stay inline and not on top of each others when i change the page resolution !

Comment: how important is  <ul class="navbar-nav w-100 justify-content-center"> ? . If you remove that div itself you will get the desired output.

Comment: well yes i get it but the 2 icons that are supposed to be in the middle of the footer are not anymore and it's not what i was looking for, i don't want to touch anything aside the navigation links.

Comment: @MoonYeah the icons aren't showing because you have to include the FontAwesome link

Comment: I mean they are still showing, but they aren't at the center of the footer anymore doing what he suggested !

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
@media screen and (max-width:768px){
  .navbar-nav{
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .navbar-nav .nav-item{
    margin: 0 10px;
  }
}
```

Your elements are going to stack on mobile regardless based off text length and screen sizes

Comment: Hello, no, actually what i'm trying to do is to force my elements in the footer to stay inline whatever resolution i use until it reachs the mobile display, like let's stay my footer switch to the mobile version at 768 pixels, well what i'm trying to do is to keep my links at the right (nous contacter, mentions légales etc...)aligned in the range of 1800px (or more) to 768px... because at some points these elements are going on top of each others before reaching 768.

Comment: Here's a https://codepen.io/shanice92/pen/RwPPdBX. I kept everything the same but took out some of your add-ons and only added mx-auto to the first ul and everything stays inline until it reaches 768px then switches to mobile view

Answer (score 0):

Your links are stacked, because they don't fit into container. You nothing can do without changing your `html` structure. And I suggest you to organize the layout ones more. Now it looks quite messy.

**Quick fix**, just to see what can be done (I see that you use `bootstrap`, so I base on that):

- **remove** `w-50` from `navbar-brand` link. It is the main reason of links stacking.
- Now you want your icons are in the center, and as I understand you want keep them inside `navbar-collapse` together with links. So **remove** `ml-auto w-100` from `ul` `navbar-nav` where are the links. **Add** `mx-auto`to `ul` where icons are, it makes them be in the center between `brand` and links.

Look into the snippet in full page mode.

```css
.footer-page {
  background-color: #d2d7e8;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  /**position:absolute;*/
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .footer-page {
    position: relative;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .footer-page {
    position: absolute;
  }
}

.navbar-brand {
  font-family: 'Raleway', regular;
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.icon {
  font-size: 0.4rem;
}

.nav-link {
  font-family: 'Raleway', Semi-Bold;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #3a5199;
  font-size: 15px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

```html
<link href="//use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<footer>
  <div class="footer-page">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom navbar-expand-md bg-faded justify-content-center">
      <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand d-flex mr-auto">Brand</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsingNavbar3">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100" id="collapsingNavbar3">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fab fa-linkedin fa-2x"></i></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item d-inline-block">
            <a class="nav-link" href="nous-contacter.php"><i class="fas fa-envelope fa-2x"></i></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav justify-content-end">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="nous-contacter.php">Nous contacter</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="mentions.html">Mentions Légales</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="CGV.html">CGV</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="presse.html">Presse</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="evenements.html">Evénements</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</footer>
```